# AJAX for displaying database data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I am currently designing a PHP script / AJAX that allows me to do monitoring, in fact on my intranet I want to retrieve a list of actions that have been stored in the database in the day. So I made a request for the moment I try to view the member asynchronously but it does not work.

In fact I wanted to display the members for testing and after adapting to recover agendas for the actions of this day and asynchronously (without reload) because I have to be able to observe the recorded data in real time.

So I did this code:

In script.js is in the header I put this:

```
function writeInDiv(text){
    var objet = document.getElementById('monitoring');
    objet.innerHTML = text;
}

function ajax()
{
    var xhr=null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "ajax.php", false);
    xhr.send(null);
    writeInDiv(xhr.responseText);
        setInterval("ajax()",5000);
}
```

Then I have two other pages, namely that displays the code, it contains the following:

```
<button onclick='javascript:ajax()'>Afficher</button>
                <div id="monitoring"></div>


<?php

$requette = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gestionnaire ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,10");
$result=mysql_query($requette) or die;
While($donne = mysql_fetch_array($requette))
{
$message = htmlentities($donne['nom']);
$pseudo = htmlentities($donne['prenom']);
?>
<b><?php var_dump($donnee); echo $pseudo; ?>:</b> <?php echo $message; ?><br />
<?php
}
?>
```

the trouble is that nothing appears I have not even an error message, though the table is filled with these fields
I tried a `var_dump` but in case like this, it is nothing.

I do not know, or it may come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, maybe the call didn't finish at the moment you pass the responseText to writeInDiv. Try the following:

```
function writeInDiv(text){
    var objet = document.getElementById('monitoring');
    objet.innerHTML = text;
}

function ajax()
{
    var xhr=null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "ajax.php", false);
    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
             writeInDiv(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    setTimeout("ajax()",5000);
}
```

or with jQuery:

```
function ajax() {
    $('#monitoring').load('ajax.php');
    setTimeout("ajax()",5000);
}
```

Also, I think you misspelled `var_dump($donnee);` it may be `var_dump($donne);`